# Error while using AjaxToolkit in visual studio 2005

Tags: .net, asp.net-ajax, .net-2.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Now I get the below error while building and running a website that uses the calender control provided in AJAX-Toolkit from Microsoft.

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.

I created the website in VS 2005, with .NET2.0.

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
</asp:CalendarExtender>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now I also tried using the older versions of the ajax toolkitv1.0.61025. But it requires to have System.Web.Extentions ddl v 1.0.61025, where as my server has v3.5. I have even tried replacing the dll with the old one(I might be wrong in doing this) it said the loaded Ajaxtoolkit does not have any contols.

So I'm kinda stuck here. any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try to download and install the ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions for the Visual Studio 2005:

[Download details: ASP.NET AJAX 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en)

Comment: Hey I tried this and it worked. I created an ajax webpage in VS 2008 and modified the web.config file so that it would point to .net 2.0 runtime. And it worked like a charm :) And the Ajax extension that you had provided link worked but it did not have any calender control extender. But still I was able to run the timer and update panel controls.